# Most efficient code for a recursion relation

Tags: recursion

What is the most efficient code for the following formula:

$y_{n+1}=\frac {2y_n-y_{n-1}+5g_n y_n+g_{n-1}y_{n-1}}{1-g_{n+1}}$

where $g_n$ is a variable.

I have tried this code

```
e=0;
x=Table[i,{i,-5,5,0.1}];
g[i_]:=g[i]=x[[i]]^2-2*e;
y[i_]:=y[i]= (2 y[i - 1] - y[i - 2] + 5*g[i - 1]*y[i - 1] + 
  g[i - 2]*y[i - 2])/(1 - g[i]);
y[0]=0;
y[1]=0.001;
```

then I can get y's by

```
yvals=Table[y[i],{i,2,10}];
```

It works, but when I change the `i` value to 100 in the last line, it runs for a very long time. It seems that it is a very inefficient code. How can I convert it into an efficient one?

Comment: Try [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) instead.

Comment: I get the result for `Table[y[i], {i, 2, 100}]` almost instantly, but with lots of `Indeterminate` expressions. By the way, you should add a space between `5g[i - 1]` and `y[i - 1]` and also between `g[i - 2]` and `y[i - 2]`. Without the spaces I got red error messages.

Comment: For `i = 41` the function returns `ComplexInfinity`. All subsequent values that depend on that result are `Indeterminate`. But the calculations are almost instantaneous.

Comment: @Roman Thanks a lot. I tried it, But it doesn't work!

Comment: For "most efficient" evaluate this `g[i_]:=(-5+(i-1)/10)^2; sol=y/.RSolve[{y[i]==(2 y[i-1] - y[i-2] + 5*g[i-1]*y[i-1] + g[i-2]*y[i-2])/(1 - g[i]),y[0]==0,y[1]==1/1000},y,i][[1]];` and let it finish. Then `Table[sol[i],{i,2,20}]+0.` will efficiently calculate your result. You can compare the results from that with your original code and should see that they are the same.

Comment: @Shredderroy so what's the solution?!

Comment: From your definition `g[41]==1` (check that carefully) and your definition of `y[i]` has `1-g[i]` in the denominator so your `y[41]` blows up. Every higher `y[i]` depends on previous `y[i]` so all subsequent values blow up. That is why `RecurrenceTable` blows up. That is why `RSolve` blows up. That is why manual calculation blows up. Does that explain it now?

Answer (score 2):

As @Roman said, the `RecurrenceTable` command worked as follows

```
RecurrenceTable[{y[i + 1] == (2 y[i] - y[i-1] + 5 * g[i] * y[i] + g[i-1]*y[i-1])/(1 - g[i+1]), y[0] == 0, y[1] == 0.001}, y, {i, 1, 101}]
```